# trying to use tipsi-twitter in snack.expo.io?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to use tipsi-twitter in snack.expo.io but I'm running into issues.  I added the following item into package.json dependencies:

```
"tipsi-twitter": "*"
```

Expo then appeared to successfully install this package.  In my App.js I included the following import:

```
import TwitterAuth from 'tipsi-twitter';
```

The import compiles successfully but when I put the following code after the imports:

```
TwitterAuth.init({
  twitter_key: '<TWITTER_KEY>',
  twitter_secret: '<TWITTER_SECRET>',
})
```

This returns an error of:

> "Cannot read property 'init' of undefined"

But this appears to be the exact implementation in the Usage section of the tipsi-twitter github page:

https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-twitter#usage

Any idea what the issue might be or how to debug?  Am I possibly missing some type of configuration step or is it possible that expo.io doesn't support this package/scenario?

Comment: You cannot use this library with expo  because it requires to link additional native modules for iOS and android.

Comment: Look at https://forums.expo.io/t/sign-a-user-with-twitter/11372

Comment: Ok so is Expo considered fairly limited?  Ie a decent beginner tool to get up and running quickly but not really appropriate for serious RN devs?  Is a tool like VS Code a more appropriate IDE choice for serious RN devs, who want maximum flexibility with minimal constraints?